# how to import multiple batch jobs in a scheduler software in one go

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have multiple batch files already created; each should be run at a specific date and time.
I want to import them quickly into a task scheduler application in one go.
I did some research but could not find any solution.
Anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go multiple times through all the
dialogs for creating a task in the Task Scheduler,
then you have two options:

- Import them from another computer
- Create them using PowerShell commands, which you reuse once you have
  created your first task (or encapsulate within a function).

These example PowerShell commands will create a task :

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' `
  -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command "& {get-eventlog -logname Application -After ((get-date).AddDays(-1)) | Export-Csv -Path c:\fso\applog.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation}"'

$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "AppLog" -Description "Daily dump of Applog"
```

For more information, see :

- [Use PowerShell to Create Scheduled Tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/)
- [How to Create Scheduled Tasks in Windows PowerShell (and Why You Should)](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-powershell-scheduled-task/)